# Rails update associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to update association inside loop

need to update each translation with hash attrs

```
  data => 
[{:name=>"string", :image_source_url=>"string", :locale=>:en},
{:name=>"string", :image_source_url=>"string", :locale=>:"en-CA"}, 
{:name=>"string", :image_source_url=>"string", :locale=>:"en-US"}, 
{:name=>"string", :image_source_url=>"string", :locale=>:fr}, 
{:name=>"string", :image_source_url=>"string", :locale=>:"fr-CA"}, 
{:name=>"string", :image_source_url=>"string", :locale=>:es}]
```

So i have tried

```
client = Client.find(2)
#Client has columns => {:name :image_source_url :locale}    

data.each do |attrs|
 client.translations.update(attrs)
end
```

but it have updated me only with last locale which is `es`

i want to update every `client=>translation`

with every field of data 
which is `{:name=>"string", :image_source_url=>"string", :locale=>:es}`

how to do it as i want?

Comment: I am sorry your question is unclear to me. What is the input (`data`?), how does `attrs` look like? Do you want to update all translations with the `attrs`? How does the expected output look like?

Comment: @spickermann quiz upd

Comment: But each iteration would override the update done in the iteration before, because the hashes have the same key. Therefore only the last hash will win.

Comment: so how to do it ?

Comment: What is a translation? Does it have an attribute that is able to store an array of hashes?

Comment: If client `has_many :translations` then you probably want to do `data.each{ |attrs| client.translations.each {|tr| tr.update(attrs)}}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to find or initialize by locale of each translation and then update them.

```
data.each do |attrs|
  translation = client.translations.find_or_initialize_by(locale: attrs[:locale])

  # it's a good practice to not do mass assignment, if you are not permitting params. 
  translation.name = attrs[:name]
  translation.image_source_url = attrs[:image_source_url]
  translation.save
end
```